# Android Scrollable TextView Border

Tags: java, android, textview, border

I have a textView in my app within which I display text and graphics.

Once the content becomes too big for the constraints of the textView, it scrolls.

Everything works perfectly, however, I want to add a border around it.  I looked here on SO and elsewhere on the internet and the only solutions I can find are adding a border around the background and then applying the background to said TextView.  This is great, however when we scroll, the content is obviously displayed *over* the border like so:

[image]

Now obviously, I know *why* this is happening, (because the border is simply part of the background), however I don't know how to bring the border above the content.

The only XML I have is the background shape, everything else is done programatically, so I'm looking for a solution which can be applied to my situation.

**XML**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
 <shape android:shape="rectangle">
 <solid android:color="#ffeeeeee"/>
 <stroke
 android:width="15dp"
 android:color="#000000"
 />
 </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

**Java Code (Class extends TextView)**

```
textLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);       
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);  
setTextSize(size);
setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textbg);
textLayout.setPadding(xPadding, yPadding, xPadding, yPadding);

Bitmap testPic= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pic1);      
Bitmap testPic2= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pic2);         

SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
builder.append(Html.fromHtml(someText)).append(" ");
builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, testPic),
builder.length() - 1, builder.length(), 0);
builder.append(Html.fromHtml(someMoreText)).append(" ");
builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, testPic2),
builder.length() - 1, builder.length(), 0);
```

Comment: set a padding in your custom `TextView`, it should help

Comment: Thanks @pskink, I can't believe I missed that.  If you wanna leave that as an answer, I will happily accept.

Comment: see my answer, but honestly the latest **EDIT:** contains the most easy solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your "border" has 15dp, so declare in dimen.xml something like this:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="border_width">15dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and use it as a padding in your custom `TextView`:

```
int pad = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.border_width);
setPadding(pad, pad, pad, pad);
```

or if your view is defined in layout xml simply add `"android:padding"` attribute

**EDIT:**

you can also add `<padding>` inside your `<shape>` and define top / left / right / bottom padding:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    ...
    <padding .../>
</shape>
```